# django rest api and backbone auth

Tags: javascript, python, django, authentication, backbone.js

The problem I am addressing is REST ful API with django for a modular backbone application.

I have a question. I know that REST is stateless, which means that in every request you have to pass the user and the password, so, in case if I have a pure rest API I am not sure, how I take care of the authentication. Probably I will have to hack some part of `collection` in the `backbone` model to maintain auth cookie and session variables.

So the question is, instead of hacking the client side, can I leverage the builting django auth, clubbed with the rest feature?

What would be an optimal way of doing it?

Comment: Are you saying you DO want to use the Django authentication system or that you DON'T want to use it? I'm not clear from your description.

Comment: i don't get it - why can't you just use normal Django auth?  REST can still involve auth cookies...  or do the different modules not share the same database?   or is the "client side" not a users' web browser but another server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#sessionauthentication) and `SessionAuthentication`